# Distance Between Two Airplanes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Two small airplanes leave the Calgary airport at the
>   same time. The first flies at $225$km/h at a heading of $320^\circ$,
>   while the second flies at $190$km/h at a heading of $70^\circ$. How far
>   apart are they after $2$ hours?

How should I proceed?

Comment: Draw it on paper, find their positions using trigonometry and find their distance with the distance formula.  Or the law of cosines.

Comment: I presume you can assume that all this happens on a Euclidean plane and does not have to take into account the curvature of the Earth. If so, you are given the two sides of a triangle and the angle between them: you have to find the third side.

Comment: @NickD at the scales relevant to this problem the impact of curvature of the earth is < 15 meters.  Which is a smaller consideration that other fudges such as can two planes really take off from the same runway at the same time.

Comment: I know, but I was just making sure that it was not an exercise in spherical trigonometry, where different formulas should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw it on paper, find their positions using trigonometry and find their distance with the distance formula.

Plane one will be at $(2*225*\cos 320, 2*225*\sin 320)$ and the other will be and $(2*190*\cos 70, 2*190*\sin 70)$.

Their distance will be $\sqrt{ (2*225\cos 320 - 2*190\cos 70)^2 +(2*225\sin 320 - 2*190\sin 70)^2}$

.....

Or you can use the law of cosines:

$D^2 = (2*225)^2 + (2*190)^2 - 2*225*190*\cos (320 - 70)$.